# How to make "baked powder" effect?

Tags: compositing-nodes

As you can see below, the object can be seen to be made of powder:

[image]

How can one recreate this effect in Blender (and the object has different colours)?

*I thought about having a mesh filled with tiny particles, but:*

*1. There would be so many particles that Blender would go laggy*

*2. It would be extremely difficult for each particle to match the colour of the mesh*

What other, better methods could I use? I don't know a node to make "powder", what about a noise texture, or are there better ways?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @gandalf3 Hi, if you won't mind, please could you provide your .blend file with the noise, as it could save some time. Thanks in advance! ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, a bump map from a noise texture is exactly the right solution for this problem. Add to that the right specular characteristics (high roughness in Cycles, large specular size in BI) and you're well on your way.

After that, just add a colored texture for the diffuse and it'll be pretty close. In fact, the noise texture actually provides RGB colors that you could just use for the color. (Often the noise texture is converted to greyscale because that's more useful than RGB, like with your bump map you're going to create, but it does actually use RGB values).